# Rails partial path when bootstrap tab active

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a profile page that contains a navigation tab with 3 tabs(account, settings, and language&display). Each tab renders a partial. What I want to achieve is that for each partial rendered the URL will change as well.

For example when Settings tab is active I want to be on settings_path, and the url: localhost:3000/settings.

[my page here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wss0T.png)

I did not find anything about partials and paths, do you have any idea about this?

Comment: It sounds like you are mixing two things here: 1) either you just make a separate page per tab, or 2) you use the bootstrap tabs as intended and just render the partials in their respective tabs.

There is the possibility to amend the URL with JS, but that feels very odd.

TL:DR: if you want routes like /settings /account /language-and-display then just make separate pages and add the active css class on the tab (at which point you could just drop the bootstrap tabs altogether and just keep the styling)

Comment: Just removed your rails 3/4/5 tags. No way your issue has to do with three different rails versions

Comment: Thank you. I managed to do it using tab partial and three different views which contain that partial. Whenever I am on the current page I add .active class to the current tab